# Dropdown menu using data- to show the submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to use the date of the navigation menu to turn on the submenu and so show their links to match. I can not change the html.
I have not the slightest idea of how to do this using "data-related-panel" someone help me?

```
<!-- nav menu -->
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-related-panel="space">Space</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-related-panel="earth">Earth Science</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-related-panel="technology">Technology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-related-panel="physics">Physics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-related-panel="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>

<!-- dropdown -->
<div id="dropdown">

    <section id="space" class="nav-panel">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Missions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Aeronautics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section id="earth" class="nav-panel">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Geology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Oceanography</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Meteorology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section id="technology" class="nav-panel">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Machines</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Computers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section id="physics" class="nav-panel">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Relativity</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quantum mechanics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Electromagnetism</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Thermodynamics</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section id="gallery" class="nav-panel">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Featured Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/L8bhsk8o/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your updated working code, replace javascript function and it will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('[data-related-panel]').click( function(){
 
  var target = $(this).data('related-panel');
    $('#dropdown').find('section').hide();
  $("#"+target).show();
 });

});
```

```css
nav{
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a{
  color: white;
}

.nav-panel{
  display: none;
}

#dropdown{
  background: blue;
}

#dropdown li{
  display: inline-block;
}

#dropdown li a{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- nav menu -->
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-related-panel="space">Space</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-related-panel="earth">Earth Science</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-related-panel="technology">Technology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-related-panel="physics">Physics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-related-panel="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>

<!-- dropdown -->
<div id="dropdown">
    <section id="space" class="nav-panel">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Missions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Aeronautics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section id="earth" class="nav-panel">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Geology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Oceanography</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Meteorology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section id="technology" class="nav-panel">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Machines</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Computers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section id="physics" class="nav-panel">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Relativity</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quantum mechanics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Electromagnetism</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Thermodynamics</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section id="gallery" class="nav-panel">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Featured Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click on an anchor in the `nav`, grab the data-attribute and use it as the id of the panel you wan to show.

```
$('nav li a').on('click', function(){
  var relatedPanel = $(this).data('related-panel');
  $('#' + relatedPanel).show(); 
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcrsvem6/6/)

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery, you need to do

```
$('a[data-related-panel="space"]')
```

Instead of data-related-space.